# Binding between two arbitrary objects in Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I'm having trouble understanding the syntax for two-way bindings in Ember.js

I have two objects which I would like to bind together, here is what I tried:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({});

App.MyPoint = Ember.Object.extend({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    init: function()
    {  
    }
});

App.PointView = Ember.Object.extend({
    point: null,
    cx: 0,
    cy: 0,
    init: function()
    {  
    }
});


var aPoint = App.MyPoint.create();

var aPointView = App.PointView.create({point: aPoint, cxBinding: "aPoint.x", cyBinding: "aPoint.y"});

console.log("Expect 0, 0: ", aPointView.get('cx'), aPointView.get('cy'));

aPoint.set('x', 10);
console.log("Expect 10, 0: ", aPointView.get('cx'), aPointView.get('cy')); // But I get 0, 0 ...
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/W9qtF/

Ideally, I'd even prefer to create the binding in PointView init(), so that PointView.create({point: aPoint}) sets up everything properly. Is that possible?

Comment: Thanks to whoever downvoted with no comments… especially since I accepted an answer a while back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've created a JSFiddle where you can play around with bindings, see http://jsfiddle.net/hVGwV/. I invoke `Ember.run.sync()` in the example to force all bindings to sync immediately.

**JavaScript:**

```
var get = Ember.get;
var view;
var point;

var flushAndDebug = function(msg) {
    if (msg) { console.log(msg);  }
    Ember.run.sync();
    point.debug();
    view.debug();
    console.log('--------------');
};

Point = Ember.Object.extend({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    debug: function() {
        console.log('point: %@/%@'.fmt(get(this, 'x'), get(this, 'y')));
    }
});

PointView = Ember.Object.extend({
    point: null,
    cxBinding: 'point.x',
    cyBinding: 'point.y',
    debug: function() {
        console.log('view: %@/%@'.fmt(get(this, 'cx'), get(this, 'cy')));
    }
});

point = Point.create();
view = PointView.create();

flushAndDebug('point and view created');

view.set('point', point);
flushAndDebug('after point has been set on view');

point.set('x', 50);
flushAndDebug('x of point has been updated');

view.set('cy', 100);
flushAndDebug('y of view has been updated');

view.set('point', null);
flushAndDebug('point of view is set to null');

view.set('cx', '200');
flushAndDebug('x of view is updated');

view.set('point', point);
flushAndDebug('point has been reassigned to view');

var newPoint = Point.create({
    x: 400,
    y: 400
});
view.set('point', newPoint);
flushAndDebug('new created point has been set as point on view');

point.set('x', 42);
flushAndDebug('original point has been updated');
```

**Output:**

```
point and view created
point: 0/0
view: (null)/(null)
--------------
after point has been set on view
point: 0/0
view: 0/0
--------------
x of point has been updated
point: 50/0
view: 50/0
--------------
y of view has been updated
point: 50/100
view: 50/100
--------------
point of view is set to null
point: 50/100
view: (null)/(null)
--------------
x of view is updated
point: 50/100
view: 200/(null)
--------------
point has been reassigned to view
point: 50/100
view: 50/100
--------------
new created point has been set as point on view
point: 50/100
view: 400/400
--------------
original point has been updated
point: 42/100
view: 400/400
--------------
```

Comment: So bindings are updated in Ember.sync.run(), now that explains why all my tests in jsfiddle where not working ;)
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Ember relies on some conventions. One these are that all objects/classes should be under the same application namespace. I.e. something like `window.App = Ember.Application.create()`.

I rewrote your example to live under the same name space – and then it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/phGeP/1/

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.MyPoint = Ember.Object.extend({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
});

App.PointView = Ember.Object.extend({
    point: null,
    cxBinding: "point.x",
    cyBinding: "point.y"
});


App.aPoint = App.MyPoint.create();

App.aPointView = App.PointView.create({point: App.aPoint});

console.log("Expect 0, 0: ", App.aPointView.get('cx'), App.aPointView.get('cy'));

App.aPoint.set('cx', 10);
console.log("Expect 10, 0: ", App.aPointView.get('cx'), App.aPointView.get('cy'));
​
```

Comment: This fiddle does not behave as expected in my browser: echoes "undefined undefined"... Something going wrong?

Comment: "All objects/classes should be under the same application namespace." Is this really the case? My app will obviously have many points (and many pointviews), I can't just use App.aPoint : how do you handle that case?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version which work:

```
MyPoint = Ember.Object.extend({
    x: 0,
    y: 0
});

PointView = Ember.Object.extend({
    point: null,

    cx: function() {
        return this.point.x;
    }.property('point'),

    cy: function() {
        return this.point.y;
    }.property('point')
});

aPoint = MyPoint.create();

aPointView = PointView.create({
    point: aPoint
})

console.log("Expect 0, 0: ", aPointView.get('cx'), aPointView.get('cy'));

aPoint.set('x', 10);
console.log("Expect 10, 0: ", aPointView.get('cx'), aPointView.get('cy')); // But I get 0, 0 ...
```

​I changed `cx` & `cy` properties to be computed according to current point's value.

Then, when you alter `aPoint`'s value, you must use `x` property, as `cx` is a property from PointView.

Comment: But then if I do aPointView.set('cx', 10), aPoint.get('x') is still 0 (so it's just an observer, not a two-way binding, right?)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bidirectional example:

Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="point-view">
    Point: ({{point.x}}, {{point.y}})

    <p>

    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="point.x"}}
    {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="point.y"}}
    {{#view Ember.Button target="App.pointController" action="resetCoordinates"}}Reset coordinates{{/view}}
</script>
```

JS:

```
App = Ember.Application.create()

App.Point = Ember.Object.extend({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,

    reset: function() {
        this.set('x', 0);
        this.set('y', 0);
    }
});

App.PointView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'point-view',
    pointBinding: 'App.pointController.point'
});

App.pointController = Ember.Object.create({
    point: null,

    init: function() {
        this.set('point', App.Point.create());
    },

    resetCoordinates: function() {
        this.point.reset();
    }
})

App.PointView.create().append();
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort but I don't want to output HTML. I'm actually trying to create a wrapper object around a Raphael path, and want to bind the coordinates of a point in my data model to the coordinates of a point in the path of the Raphael object. I managed to do so with pangratz's example above tho, and using computed properties to manipuate the Raphael object :)